# How to login in flask?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I would like to know how to login a user in flask by comparing usernames and passwords from data base.
If error is the username doesnt exist flash "User doesnt exist" 
if that password doesnt match with the users password flash "worng passsword"
and on success flash "You are logged in"

Right now I have this code.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME']:
        error = 'Invalid username'
    elif request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
        error = 'Invalid password'
    else:
        session['logged_in'] = True
        flash('You were logged in')
        return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

I would like to change the username and password check from db rahter than app.config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) and then simply check your database for a matching user. Also, use [bcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-bcrypt/) to hash passwords. Storing passwords in plaintext is **not acceptable under any circumstances**.

```
user = User.query.filter_by(username=request.form['USERNAME']).first()
if not user:
    error = 'Invalid username'
elif bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['password'], user.password) != hashed:
    error = 'Invalid password'
else:
    session['user_id'] = user.id  # makes more sense than storing just a bool
    flash('You were logged in')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

Of course you might need to define your user table first. Here's an example:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
```

To make the actual user available I'd suggest you to use a before_request function that checks for `session['user_id']` and stores `User.query.get(session['user_id'])` in `g.user` if the user is logged in.